# selectonemenu not appearing primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to make primefaces elements appear on my pages by taking code from the showcase, the menu worked well after some modifications but the selectonemenu refuses to appear.
it's not showing anything in the layout unit.
This is my xhtml code :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <h:head>
   <title>Consultation Travaux Soumis (Etudiant)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-widget,.ui-widget .ui-widget {
            font-size: 90% !important;
        }
    </style>
  </h:head>
<body>
<p:layout fullPage="true">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="158" header="Intranet" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
          <h:graphicImage value="/img/Logo.jpg" width="110" height="110"/>
        <h:outputText value="   Consultation de la liste de travaux" />

    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Menu" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">


    <h:form id="pmenu">

         <p:menu style="width:90%">

            <p:submenu label="Navigation">
                <p:menuitem value="Acceuil"  action="#" immediate="true" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Deconnexion" action="#{PagesController.logout}" immediate="true" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-locked"/>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="Services">

                <p:menuitem value="Emploi du Temps" actionListener="#"  immediate="true" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-suitcase" disabled="true"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Relevé de Notes" actionListener="#"  immediate="true" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed" disabled="true"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Remise de Doc." url="/secure/remisetrEt.xhtml"  immediate="true" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open" />              

            </p:submenu>



            <p:submenu label="Infos">
                <p:menuitem value="Réclamation" actionListener="#"  immediate="true" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" />
                <p:menuitem value="A Propos" actionListener="#"  immediate="true" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-info" />
            </p:submenu>

         </p:menu>
    </h:form>

    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">

        <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5"> 
        <p:selectOneMenu>  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>   
        </h:form>            
    </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us the code of the layout? Your error isn't in this snippet.

Comment: Dont you have to bind your selectonemenu to a attribute of your managed bean?

Comment: i edited and posted the full code.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Which version of primefaces are you using?  Which app server are you deploying to?  Which browser have you tested in?  Is there anything else on the page besides the selectonemenu?

Try the following.  Work with Primefaces 4 on Glassfish 3.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />

        <title>Test</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{request.contextPath}/css/default.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{request.contextPath}/css/custom.css" />
    </f:facet>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>
 <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5"> 
     <p:selectOneMenu>  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
     </p:selectOneMenu>
 </h:panelGrid>   
</h:form>       
</h:body>

</f:view>

</html>
```

Comment: tried it it gave a Parsing /secure/consultationEt.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have to bind my `selectonemenu` to a property of a managed bean I have.